# How to run the same python script with different module import?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I would like to run a same script but with two different softwares api.

What I have :
-One module for each software where I have the same classes and methods names.
-One construction script where I need to call these classes and method.

I would like to not duplicate the construction code, but rather run the same bit of code just by changing the imported module.

Exemple :

```
first_software_module.py

import first_software_api
class Box(x,y,z):
   init():
       first_software_api.makeBox()
```

```
second_software_module.py

import second_software_api
class Box(x,y,z):
    init():
        second_software_api.makeBox()
```

```
construction.py

first_box = Box(1,2,3)
```

And I would like to run construction.py with the first module, then with the second module.
I tryed with imports, execfile, but none of these solutions seems to work.

What i would like to do :

```
import first_software_module
run construction.py

import second_software_module
run construction.py
```

Comment: Why not pass the module name to `construction` & let it import it & run it?

Comment: Is it possible to do that inside an other python script ? Because I have to run the construction script inside a larger script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by passing a command line argument to `construction.py`.

`construction.py`

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: python3 construction.py <module>')
    exit(1)

if sys.argv[1] == 'first_software_module':
    import first_software_module
elif sys.argv[1] == 'second_software_module':
    import second_software_module

box = Box(1, 2, 3)
```

You could then call `construction.py` with each import type from a shell script, say `main.sh`.

`main.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 construction.py first_software_module
python3 construction.py second_software_module
```

Make the shell script executable using `chmod +x main.sh`. Run it as `./main.sh`.

**Alternatively**, if you do not want to use a shell script, and want to do it in pure Python, you could do the following:

`main.py`

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python3', 'construction.py', 'first_software_module'])
subprocess.run(['python3', 'construction.py', 'second_software_module'])
```

and run `main.py` as you normally would using `python3 main.py`.

Comment: Actually I need to run it from inside an other python script, handling path to the software, file saves, etc...
Is it possible with that solution ?

Comment: I've added how you can do it in Python. Does the modification work for you?

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a command-line argument that will tell your script which module to import. There are many ways to do this, but I'm going to demonstrate with the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the construction')
parser.add_argument('--module', nargs=1, type=str, required=True, help='The module to use for the construction', choices=['module1', 'module2'])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now, `args.module` will contain the contents of the argument you passed. Using this string and an `if-elif` ladder (or the `match-case` syntax in 3.10+) to import the correct module, and alias it as (let's say) `driver`.

```
if args.module[0] == "module1":
    import first_software_api as driver
    print("Using first_software_api")
elif args.module[0] == "module2":
    import second_software_api as driver
    print("Using second_software_api")
```

Then, use `driver` in your `Box` class:

```
class Box(x,y,z):
   def __init__(self):
       driver.makeBox()
```

Say we had this in a file called `construct.py`. Running `python3 construct.py --help` gives:

```
usage: construct.py [-h] --module {module1,module2}

Run the construction

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --module {module1,module2}
                        The module to use for the construction
```

Running `python3 construct.py --module module1` gives:

```
Using first_software_api
```